# Crawl links with rel="nofollow" using wget

Tags: bash, grep, wget

I have a site (http://a-site.com) with many links like that. How can I use wget to crawl and grep this type of links to a file?

```
<a href="/user/333333/follow_user" class="btn" rel="nofollow">Follow</a>
```

I tried this but this command won't get me the links with nofollow.

```
$ wget --no-verbose -r -l1 http://a-site.com 2>&1
```

Comment: hack solution - open wget source and search and hack "nofollow" string

Comment: Is there any other tool that does allow nofollow links?

Comment: i don't know, we used lynx for similar functionality once.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

info from here:

http://skeena.net/kb/wget%20ignore%20robots.txt

try:

```
wget -erobots=off http://your.site.here
```

Comment: this fails on deny's website. .. all I want is to see the menu without having to enter location data

Comment: try play with user agent etc.

Comment: with version 1.21.2, it works, with 1.20.3, it does not.